# How to uninstall Comodo Antivirus in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, antivirus, purge

I want to remove virus from my PC. Therefore I install Comodo Anti Virus in my Ubuntu desktop. Now, when the virus is removed, I want to uninstall the antivirus.

I have used this command line in Terminal (`sudo apt-get purge cav-linux`) but it is showing error. How to fix this, Please?

Comment: Please tell us what the error is.

Comment: What worked? Think about it this way: Somebody who will have the same problem might find your question, but no answer. Could you please either delete your question if it is none any more, or answer it?

Comment: -1 Would downvote even Gaurav Kumar comment if I could. Nor question nor comment are constructive and both are useless as not explaining what was done and what the error was, it wont help anyone who come by.

Comment: Ah, after a long time I am active on this question, Martin Ueding. When I commented "It worked. Thanks" I was referring to a guy who had posted a comment to which I replied, but when I am seeing it now the comment s deleted.So that's why you are asking "What worked". So I am telling you, I used this command, " sudo apt-get --purge remove cav-linux ". Thanks for pointing it out though. I wouldn't have noticed that then.

Answer (score 14):

I was having the similar trouble...
The command that this guy was using was wrong...

I removed comodo antivirus using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cav-linux
```

it worked